# How can I exclude columns from an SQL selection?

Tags: sql

Basically I'd like to have an IF or a Case statement that adds an extra column to the selection depending on a variable value. My idea was something like:

```
DECLARE @MyCounter bit;
SET @MyCounter = 0; 

SELECT
    [column1],
    [column2],
    CASE WHEN @MyCounter = 0
    THEN
        [column3],
    ELSE 
        NULL
    END
    [column4],
    [column5],
FROM Table;
```

So if @MyCounter = 0 i need 5 columns if it's anything else, I need 4.

Comment: `if @MyCounter = 5 then begin //select 5 columns end else //select 4 columns begin end`

Comment: is `null` in the column ok if the variable is 0?

Comment: @vkp I do not want the column at all

Comment: Potentially you could use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), but personally I'd use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @austinwernli Let's say i have a few more variables, for example 4, would that mean I need to write all the 16 variations?

Comment: Either use [IF..ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) or create dynamic sql query and execute. Like you mentioned if you have a lot of variables and conditions, rather just go dynamic than if..else

Comment: @Harkat Why are you trying to make a stored procedure do everything for these 16 variations? Would it be more appropriate to split these up into separate procedures doing just what they need to do? Would it be bad if these columns just contained null and you handle it in the consumer?